# Arrays in Angular 4 components. Unrecognized input parameters

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have a problem with the array declaration and the string interpolation in Angular 4 with TypeScript.
If I create this classes:

```
export class MyArrayProperty {
 property1: string;
 property2: string;
}

export class MyComponent {
 @Input() object: ComplexObject;
 myArray: MyArrayProperty[];
}
```

The ComplexObject is an Object with a lot of property:

```
ComplexObject {
  myNumber: number;
  myString: string;
  // etc..
}
```

If I tried to create an array of instances of MyArrayProperty inside the component MyComponent, in this way:

```
 export class MyComponent {
   @Input() object: ComplexObject;
   myArray: MyArrayProperty[] = [{
     property1: 'hello',
     property2: this.object.myString
   }];
 }
```

The field `property1` is displayed correctly on the HTML page with the string interpolation: `{{myArrayInstance.property1}}` (`myArrayInstance` is obtained by ngFor).
But the `property2` does not appear with string interpolation `{{myArrayInstance.property2}}`, even though `this.object.myString` is actually a string and I received an input object.
How does this happen and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: where you are passing the object to this component? kindly post the code

Answer (score 0):

First of all why you're using a class for `MyArrayProperty`? You're just using it as a type, so you should go for an interface.

```
export interface MyArrayProperty {
 property1: string;
 property2: string;
}
```

Second, your code will fail because your're trying to access the property `myString` of the member `object` on component creation. But `object` is `undefined` before `ngOnInit`. Therefore you're accessing a property of `undefined`.

To solve your problem you could use a getter which transforms the `object` member to be displayed in your template.

```
export class MyComponent {
  @Input()
  public object: ComplexObject;

  public get myArray() {
    return Object.keys(this.object || {}).map(key => {
       return {
         property1: 'hello',
         property2: this.object[key]
       } as MyArrayProperty;
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that, the moment you are assigning the `this.object.myString`, the `object` is not available.

you can use `ngOnChanges()` which is executed everytime the `@input` property changes which in your case is `object` being inject in you component.

You can do something like this,

```
ngOnChanges (changes: SimpleChanges) {
if(this.object) {
myArray = [{
   property1: 'hello',
   property2: this.object.myString
   }];
}}
```

To use `ngOnChanges()` you need to implement `OnChanges` interface to your component.

More on OnChanges() [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)
and 
[Angular LifeCycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: Error: Property 'object' does not exist on type 'SimpleChanges'.